# Calculate duration (age)

Tags: r

I would like to calculate duration between 2 date (age in years)

Thius is the data

```
> dput(Data)
structure(list(ID = c("ABC001", "ABC002", "ABC003", "ABC004"), 
    RACE = c("John", "Jack", "Jill", "James"), `DATE OF BIRTH` = structure(c(1449187200, 
    1454457600, 1484438400, 1484524800), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `DATE OF ADMISSION` = structure(c(1575417600, 
    1522800000, 1505433600, 1547683200), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), AGE = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have already added a column for the age.

This is the code I have tried:

```
AGE<-as.Date(`DATE OF ADMISSION`,"%d-%B-%Y") - as.Date(`DATE OF BIRTH``,"%d-%B-%Y")
```

but it's not working.

Comment: You've got an extra \`. You're also referring to variables that probably don't exist. There's a column in your data frame called "DATE OF ADMISSION", but that doesn't mean you have a variable in your environment that you can call with the same name. Is this the code that you're using, on its own and not inside a `with` or `mutate` call? If so, the issue is probably these typos

Comment: You can do this is a single base R line:  `within(df, age <- difftime(``DATE OF ADMISSION``,``DATE OF BIRTH``, "days"))`.  If you want years, you could wrap `as.numeric(...)/365.35` around the call to `difftime`.  (Note that I  having Markdown issue here.  Where you see double backticks, use one.  Or renamed your columns to not contain spaces to not require backticks to protect the spaces.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `tbl_df` and it is already in the datetime class, so there is no need to do any conversion

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
      mutate(new = `DATE OF ADMISSION` - `DATE OF BIRTH`)
```

To get this in 'years', use the `time_length`

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(new = lubridate::time_length(`DATE OF ADMISSION` -
           `DATE OF BIRTH`, "years"))
# A tibble: 4 x 6
#  ID     RACE  `DATE OF BIRTH`     `DATE OF ADMISSION` AGE     new
#  <chr>  <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>              <lgl> <dbl>
#1 ABC001 John  2015-12-04 00:00:00 2019-12-04 00:00:00 NA    4.00 
#2 ABC002 Jack  2016-02-03 00:00:00 2018-04-04 00:00:00 NA    2.17 
#3 ABC003 Jill  2017-01-15 00:00:00 2017-09-15 00:00:00 NA    0.666
#4 ABC004 James 2017-01-16 00:00:00 2019-01-17 00:00:00 NA    2.00
```

Comment: im getting error after trying this.Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'df1' not found
>

Comment: Thanks alot. Managed to change it.